# Как соединить два коммита , если они находятся в середине дерева

Tags: git

Есть 12 коммитов , и как можно объединить к пример 6 и 9 , не потеряв при этом коммиты между ними .

Comment: все эти коммиты, начиная с шестого, будут **потеряны**, ведь изменятся их хэш-суммы.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3921708/4827341

Answer (score 3):

делаете интерактивный ребейз достаточно глубоко (или указав хэш нужного коммита)

```
git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

получаете редактор вида

```
pick 6e6d42e sample commit 2
pick 393eb9c sample commit 3
pick 1731ac2 sample commit 4
pick 5924b37 sample commit 5
pick 0043963 sample commit 6
```

в редакторе переставляете коммиты так, как вам хочется и указываете действие squash для того коммита, который нужно слить

```
pick 6e6d42e sample commit 2
pick 1731ac2 sample commit 4
pick 5924b37 sample commit 5
s 393eb9c sample commit 3  <----- переставить и слить с 5-м
pick 0043963 sample commit 6
```

дальше следуете инструкции в консоли - разрешаете конфликты и завершаете ребейз

Answer (score 0):

Вроде можно сделать следующим образом: Воспользуйтесь командой 'git checkout commit', вместо 'commit' впишите хеш 6 коммита и от него создайте новую ветку. После вернитесь на 9 коммит и оттуда произведите мерж.